# Computing perron vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the right and left perron vectors and compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\rho(A)^{-1} \rho(A))^n$.

**Attempt:**

Let $0<a,b<1$ and $A =\begin{bmatrix} 1-a & b\\ a & 1-b \end{bmatrix}$. Then through computation we have the eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1, \lambda_2=-(a+b-1)$. Now by [Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) $0<\rho(A)$ with algebraic multiplicity $1$, thus $\rho(A)=1$, also by Perron-Frob Theorem there exists a unique $x>0$ such that $Ax=\rho(A)x=x$. From here I'm stuck since what I've computed for $x=[0 \; 0]^T$.  
 Any help would be appreciated!